# Output from apply function in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, apply

Consider the following dataframe:

```
Data=[[0,'ABC SCHOOL BOARDING',['ABC','SCHOOL','BOARDING']],
      [1,'UNIVERSITY BOARDING INSTITUTE',['UNIVERSITY','BOARDING','INSTITUTE']],
      [2,'MARIE INSTITUTE SCHOOL',['MARIE', 'INSTITUTE','SCHOOL']],
      [3,'RALPH ELEMENTARY SCHOOL',['RALPH','ELEMENTARY','SCHOOL']],
      [4,'BOARDING SCHOOL',['BOARDING','SCHOOL']]]

df=pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['id','name', 'name_list'])
```

I am using the apply function that returns a dictionary for each row:

```
def classify(row, df_start, df_end):
    #df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['word','classification'])
    d={}
    for word in row.name_list:
        flag=False
        if word in df_start.values:
            #df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'word':[word], 'classification':['start']}))
            d[word]='start'
            flag=True
        if word in df_end.values:
            #df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'word':[word], 'classification':['end']}))
            d[word]='end'
            flag=True
        if (not flag):
            #df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'word':[word], 'classification':['none']}))
            d[word]='none'
    return d
```

I am calling the above function using apply over every row:

```
df_start=pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])
df_end=pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])
df_start= df.name.str.split().str.get(0).drop_duplicates(keep="last")
df_end= df.name.str.split().str.get(-1).drop_duplicates(keep="last")

d={}

d = df.apply(classify, args=[df_start, df_end],axis=1)

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k)
```

However, the key values in the returned dictionary are printed as follows:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

While the values for the dictionary are the following:

```
{'ABC': 'start', 'SCHOOL': 'end', 'BOARDING': 'end'}
{'UNIVERSITY': 'start', 'BOARDING': 'end', 'INSTITUTE': 'end'}
{'MARIE': 'start', 'INSTITUTE': 'end', 'SCHOOL': 'end'}
{'RALPH': 'start', 'ELEMENTARY': 'none', 'SCHOOL': 'end'}
{'BOARDING': 'end', 'SCHOOL': 'end'}
```

When printed in the function `classify` the key and value are as expected. These the keys:

```
ABC
SCHOOL
BOARDING
UNIVERSITY
BOARDING
INSTITUTE
MARIE
INSTITUTE
SCHOOL
RALPH
ELEMENTARY
SCHOOL
BOARDING
SCHOOL
```

And these the values:

```
start
end
end
start
end
end
start
end
end
start
none
end
end
end
```

Why the numbers are added when returning from apply function? How can I get the expected dictionary to be converted into a DataFrame?

Thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apply function in your case will return a pandas Series, not a dictionary. Check with `type(d)`. To concat the values of d into one dictionary, use the following code:

```py
da = {}
for r in d:
    da.update(r)
```

Comment: My bad, `Return Type: Pandas Series after applied function/operation.` I was expecting a dataframe as return.